# class 'CakeLog' not found error in cakephp 2.1

Tags: php, cakephp-2.1

I have installed cakephp 2.1 in windows server 2008 and it gives me following error

> Fatal Error: Class "CakeLog" not found in
>   "C:\wamp\www\foldername\app\Config\bootstrap.php" on line 172
>
> Fatal Error: Class "CakeLog" not found in
>   "C:\wamp\www\foldername\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php" on line 200

Whereas when I am running it on window 7 32 bit server, it's working smoothly.

Can anyone please tell me how can I make it run on windows server 2008.

Comment: As a first step, Google `Class "CakeLog" not found`. There seem to be some helpful results.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this issue several times and my resolution has always been

1. if this installation was copied from a previous application delete the files && folders in the tmp directory and recreated them and all the subfolders e.g cache + (models,persistent,views) and logs
2. Make sure that the /tmp directory is "Write-able" chmod -R 777

p.s the error message given is not descriptive enough

Answer (score 2):

I have searched for a solution for this let me know if it worked for you or not because this solved my problem

In cake version CakePHP v 2.0 I simply  commented the following code in C:\wamp\www\foldername\app\Config\bootstrap.php file

```
 //Configures default file logging options

App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');CakeLog::config('debug', array('engine' => 'FileLog','types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),'file' => 'debug',));
CakeLog::config('error', array('engine' => 'FileLog','types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency'),'file' => 'error',));
```